# How can I export "filtered" grid in vaadin 8?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I have export method to csv format for all grid data. If my user filter content in the grid, it is only afected to view, and export button keeps exporting all grid data. How can I only export filtered grid data?

```
/**
 * generateCSVExportFile
 */ 
public void generateCSVExportFile() {
    try { // Try
        // Actual date
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        Date date = new Date();

        // (1) Generate String buffer
        String string2csv = generateCSVBufferString();

        // (2) Generate file downloader file
        fileDownloaderCSV.setFileDownloadResource(createResourceFromString(
                SAMPLE_CSV_FILE + dateFormat.format(date) + CONF_CSV_EXTENSION, string2csv));
        fileDownloaderCSV.extend(generateCSVFileButton);

    } catch (Exception error) { // Catch
        logger.error(error.toString(), error);
    }
}
```

Thank you

best regards

Answer (score 3):

One alternative for this is to use [fetchItemsWithRange](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.6.2/com/vaadin/data/provider/DataCommunicator.html#fetchItemsWithRange-int-int-) method from DataCommunicator, which returns List of items after sorting and filtering. So I assume it is exactly what you want

```
grid.getDataCommunicator().fetchItemsWithRange(0, grid.getDataCommunicator().getDataProviderSize());
```